# Track packages by date range FedEx API

Tags: c#, fedex

In FedEx's API all I've found so far is how to track a package by tracking number. But I need a method that lets me pull down tracking information on all of my packages, without specifying a tracking number. Or an API call that would return a list of tracking numbers by date modified, which I could then use to get tracking information. Does anyone know how I can pull this off?

Comment: Could you please share the API reference? I don't think they'd have implemented a way of getting tracking information without having a tracking number. There should be some way of stating the package is "yours", so your best bet would be to look for something that can return tracking info you need by providing your User ID. Otherwise it leaves you with multiple calls for each of the package and some logic to filter the result based on the date range.

Comment: @Ghukas Sure, thanks, it's a PDF: https://www.fedex.com/us/developer/downloads/pdf/2019/FedEx_WebServices_DevelopersGuide_v2019.pdf

Comment: @Ghukas And my issue is that where my internal app fits in, I don't have tracking numbers. I would be bringing down all our FedEx packages and looking for one of our customer numbers somewhere on the package's info, and integrating that with another internal website.

Comment: 25.1 Tracking Shipments says there are other ways to track:
"purchase order (PO) number, customer reference, invoice, Bill of Lading (BOL), part number, or Transportation Control Number (TCN). Tracking by something other than tracking number also requires inclusion of Sender's account number
and should contain secure tracking content". And they provide a way to track packages in batches by providing up to 30 tracking info in a single request. This might not give you the ability to get what you need immediately but will reduce the number of calls.

Comment: In general, I think FedEx has eliminated the risk of getting their APIs under high load by requiring certain order information from the client before returning any shipment info. But, if the orders have been put by using a single customer reference (I mean the Company, not the receiver of the package) it will be easier to pull the data and get your result.

Comment: @Ghukas Hmm it seems their API wants some type of tracking number. In their test DB when I just pass the shipment account number and a date range I get `This tracking number cannot be found. Please check the number or contact the sender.`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213721/discussion-between-ghukas-and-john).